# How do i search from items of list widget ??,

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

[image]

as seen in the image above my QListWIdget is populated with items, i want to take input from Qlineedit which is "Guide" in this case and when i click search Qpushbutton, the QlistWidget should show that items which contain text "Guide ", maybe highlight them.

Any idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd consider to use a QStandardItemModel+QListView with QSortFilterProxyModel for filtering instead of QListWidget.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate in all items.
for this i suggest to copy all the elements in `QStringList` then you can find your "Guide" there

```
QStringList strList;
for(int i=0; i < ui->listWidget->count(); i++)
{
    QListWidgetItem* item = ui->listWidget->item(i);
    if(notContaninKey(item))
        item->setHidden(true);
}
```

you can change `ui->listWidget` with your variable name.
and you need to implement notContainKey function to search in items